# How to do screen sharing in Electron App?

Tags: node.js, typescript, electron, webrtc, electron-forge

I'm trying to build two apps for screen sharing in a LAN environment using Electron, React and TypeScript. One app will capture the screen stream and do UDP broadcasting, and another app which will run on multiple devices will receive the stream and display it. I've looked into the `desktopCapturer` API provided by Electron, but there was an error when I run this code sample:

```
desktopCapturer
      .getSources({ types: ["window", "screen"] })
      .then(async (sources) => {
        for (const source of sources) {
          if (source.name === "Entire Screen") {
            const displayMediaOptions = {
              video: {
                cursor: "always",
                mandatory: {
                  chromeMediaSource: "desktop",
                  chromeMediaSourceId: source.id,
                  maxWidth: 800,
                  maxHeight: 700,
                },
              },
              audio: false,
            };

            try {
              const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(
                displayMediaOptions
              );
              handleStream(stream);
            } catch (e) {
              handleError(e);
            }
            return;
          }
        }
      });
```

The error is:

```
Argument of type '{ video: { cursor: string; mandatory: { chromeMediaSource: string; chromeMediaSourceId: string; maxWidth: number; maxHeight: number; }; }; audio: boolean; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'MediaStreamConstraints'.
  Types of property 'video' are incompatible.
    Type '{ cursor: string; mandatory: { chromeMediaSource: string; chromeMediaSourceId: string; maxWidth: number; maxHeight: number; }; }' is not assignable to type 'boolean | MediaTrackConstraints'.
      Type '{ cursor: string; mandatory: { chromeMediaSource: string; chromeMediaSourceId: string; maxWidth: number; maxHeight: number; }; }' has no properties in common with type 'MediaTrackConstraints'.ts(2345)
```

I looked into the `MediaTrackConstraints` and find it does not support the `mandatory` property. I also found WebRTC might be helpful, but don't know if it's going work in LAN environment without any servers suport?

So I'm wondering is there any workarounds for this issue or what other technologies I can use to do screen sharing in a local network?

Comment: Does using `getDisplayMedia` instead of `getUserMedia`  work? Alternatively, it seems this could be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48026144/typescript-prevents-me-from-passing-the-correct-constraints-to-getusermedia?rq=1

Comment: `getDisplayMedia` is not working. The error is `property 'getDisplayMedia' does not exist on type 'MediaDevices'`

Comment: OK, I've made the error gone by casting the `navigator.mediaDevices` to `any`. But how can I broadcast the MediaStream object to multiple clients?

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the stream sources and you are creating the stream from the electron side instead get the list of ids of the sources using the desktop capturer and create the video stream in the renderer side that is the react side.

Following is what i have done to achieve this.

In electron preload

```js
getDesktopSources: async () =>
  await desktopCapturer
    .getSources({
      types: ['window', 'screen'],
    })
    .then((sources) =>
      sources.map((source) => ({
        id: source.id,
        name: source.name,
        appIconUrl: source?.appIcon?.toDataURL(),
        thumbnailUrl: source?.thumbnail
          ?.resize({ height: 160 })
          .toDataURL(),
      }))
    )
```

This preload function is called in react side as below

```js
const turnScreenSharingOn = useCallback(async () => {
  const sources = await window.electron.media.getDesktopSources();
  setScreenSources(sources);
  setScreenSharePopupVisible(true);
}, []);
```

I show these sources in a popup for the user to choose what screen needs to be shared. On selecting the following function executes.

```js
const onScreenChoose = useCallback(
  async (sourceId: string, cb?: () => void) => {
    const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
      audio: false,
      video: {
        mandatory: {
          chromeMediaSource: 'desktop',
          chromeMediaSourceId: sourceId,
        },
      } as MediaTrackConstraints,
    });
    
    handleStream(stream)    

    cb?.();
  },
  []
);
```

The track is only created on the react side using the source id captured from the electron side using the desktop capturer.